# Building binutils in cygwin error on 'make' command

Tags: gcc, build, binutils

I use the cygwin to build the binutils for my platform. I followed the [GCC-Cross-Compiler](https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler#Which_compiler_version_to_choose) article and stack on 'make' command. The command i used:

```
export PREFIX="$HOME/opt/cross"
```

```
../binutils-2.42/configure --target=amd64 --prefix="$PREFIX" --with-sysroot --disable-nls --disable-werror
make CFLAGS="-march=x86-64-v2" && make install
```

on the 'make' command it thrown me following errors:

```
../../binutils-2.42/libiberty/pex-unix.c:259:14: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘wait’; did you mean ‘cwait’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  259 |       cpid = wait (status);
      |              ^~~~
      |              cwait
../../binutils-2.42/libiberty/pex-unix.c: In function ‘save_and_install_fd’:
../../binutils-2.42/libiberty/pex-unix.c:385:11: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fcntl’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  385 |   flags = fcntl (old_fd, F_GETFD);
      |           ^~~~~
../../binutils-2.42/libiberty/pex-unix.c:385:26: error: ‘F_GETFD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  385 |   flags = fcntl (old_fd, F_GETFD);
      |                          ^~~~~~~
../../binutils-2.42/libiberty/pex-unix.c:385:26: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
../../binutils-2.42/libiberty/pex-unix.c:398:20: error: ‘FD_CLOEXEC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  398 |       if ((flags & FD_CLOEXEC) == 0 && fcntl (old_fd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) < 0)
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~
../../binutils-2.42/libiberty/pex-unix.c:398:55: error: ‘F_SETFD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  398 |       if ((flags & FD_CLOEXEC) == 0 && fcntl (old_fd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) < 0)
      |                                                       ^~~~~~~
../../binutils-2.42/libiberty/pex-unix.c:411:31: error: ‘F_DUPFD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  411 |       new_fd = fcntl (old_fd, F_DUPFD, 3);
      |                               ^~~~~~~
../../binutils-2.42/libiberty/pex-unix.c: In function ‘restore_fd’:
../../binutils-2.42/libiberty/pex-unix.c:445:19: error: ‘FD_CLOEXEC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  445 |       if (flags & FD_CLOEXEC)
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~
../../binutils-2.42/libiberty/pex-unix.c:447:29: error: ‘F_SETFD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  447 |       return fcntl (old_fd, F_SETFD, flags);
```

(There is much more but i think no sense to put all)

Tryed to some adjust compilation flags, tryed without removed -march=x86_64-v2 specification.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGfB7.jpg)